# JQuery function: prepend <form> that calls another JQuery function

Tags: jquery

Long time reader - first time poster.

I got this JQuery function and I'm trying to execute it it from another JQuery function:

```
$(".delete_item").click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var Id = element.attr("id");
    var split = Id.split('_');
    var row = 'row_' + split[1];

    var dataString = 'item=' + split[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_remove.jsp",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {

           removeRow(row);

        }

    });
```

The problem that I'm having is when I'm using prepend in the success: function() of another function, trying to call this function. It doesn't work:

```
$("#table")
    .prepend($('<tr>')
        .prepend($('<td>')
            .prepend($('<form>')
                .attr('method','post')
                .attr('id','delete_1234')
                .attr('name','delete_1234')
                .prepend($('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'image')
                    .attr('name','Delete')
                    .attr('src', 'images/button_delete.gif')
                    .attr('class','delete_item')
                    .attr('id','delete_1234')
                )
            )
        )
```

The function (the first one) that I'm trying to call from within the success function works fine when used from the html page, but not when calling it from prepend. In stead of calling the 'delete_item' class function, it just reloads the page. Hopefully I'm making myself understandable and someone has an idea of how to get around this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I get it, but is the problem that the click function is not working on elements inserted into the DOM, if so you need to use delegated events by using something like jQuery's on() instead of click().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean that when you create the `input[type="image"]` programmatically, the "click" event handler is not executed when you click it ?

This is because you bind the click event with

```
$(".delete_item").click(function() {...}`
```

the element does not probably exist yet so no event is binded to it.

You should use event delegation with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)):

```
$('#table').on('click', '.delete_item', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

What does the above code do ?

- Delegate the event handling to element with id `#table` (basically an existing parent element).
- When a click event is captured, if the target is an element with class `.delete_item`, execute the handler.

I invite you to read about [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to get more info and example on what is event delegation and how it works

Comment: I didn't see anything after "What does this code do ?". Saw it after I posted it. I'm going to try and wrap my head around .on(). Hopefully I'll figure this out.

Comment: yep, I'll do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I actually just had to replace 
  
$(".delete_item").click(function() {
   
 <--- with --->
  
$('#table').on('click', '.delete_item', function(e) {
.. thanks alot for the help. You're a genius :D

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. When it happened to you 10 times already, you start seeing the problem right away :o) Don't forget to accept the answer ;-)